# Pass PHP array to JS - PHP Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a PHP array

```
$logEnabled = explode(',',$baby->logEnabled);
// dd($logEnabled);
```

result

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "pee"
  1 => " poop"
  2 => " feed"
]
```

I'm trying to pass that to JS , I did this

console.log(`{{json_encode($logEnabled) }}`);

I kept getting

```
[&quot;pee&quot;,&quot; poop&quot;,&quot; feed&quot;]
```

I want to see `[pee,poop,feed]`

Any hints for me

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
$logEnabled = "[".$baby.logEnabled."]"
```

Now, `$logEnabled` contains the JS array.

Comment: I do that in JS or in PHP ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this I'm sure this will work

`var app = @json($logEnabled);`